# Multiple COUNT expressions based on different criteria in the same query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to create a summary based on data from one table in Access, but having some expected issues which I hope someone can resolve.

Table 1 looks like this

```
Region || Case ID || Tasked || Visited
```

For each region I would like to show three fields.

1. a Total Column (count of case IDs)
2. Total Tasked (where Tasked = Yes)
3. Total Visited (where Total Visited = Yes).

Creating the Total Column is fine, however, once I started adding in `WHERE` clauses = Yes, I obviously lose data in the total column.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: Have you tried `SUM(IIf(Tasked=True,1,0)) AS TotalTasked`?

Comment: This would work, however, I don't want sum all true values, as some values = No

Comment: ive changed true to "Yes" and this works fine

Comment: @GordThompson your answer is correct! However, I benchmarked the difference in efficiency between `ABS` and `IIF` and found that `ABS` is 12 times faster.

Comment: @EMett I was unable to reproduce your results. See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 1):

I was intrigued by E Mett's test results regarding performance so I tried to reproduce them. Unfortunately, I could not.

I ran the tests against a table with 1 million rows residing in a back-end .accdb file on a network share. I ran three tests (re-loading the front-end .accdb each time) and averaged the results.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS TotalRows, 
    SUM(IIf(Tasked=True,1,0)) AS TaskedRows 
FROM TestData
```

Test runs: 24.8, 24.0, 23.8 seconds
Average: 24.2 seconds

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS TotalRows, 
    SUM(Abs(Tasked)) AS TaskedRows 
FROM TestData
```

Test runs: 22.3, 23.8, 24.9 seconds
Average: 23.7 seconds

Based on those results `SUM(Abs())` might be very slightly faster than `SUM(IIf())`, but certainly not 12x faster.

If speed is an issue and you had the foresight to put an index on the [Tasked] field, then a truly faster approach would be

```
SELECT 
    DCount("*", "TestData") AS TotalRows, 
    DCount("*", "TestData", "Tasked=True") AS TaskedRows
```

Test runs: 2.1, 3.5, 2.3 seconds
Average: 2.6 seconds

As always, query performance tuning can be an interesting game in itself.

Comment: I have opened a new question to show my test: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23855662/which-function-is-faster-abs-or-iif

Comment: Without a function call; `SUM(-Tasked) AS TaskedRows`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

`SUM(ABS(Tasked)) AS TotalTasked`

The `ABS` function will convert the `-1` to `1`

`Abs` is about 12 times faster than `IIf`! If you have thousands of records, it may make a difference.